# "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError" while running "model_main_tf2.py" for training object detection model in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

Many people have also faced this issue, but it alway seems to have happened because of some mistake in the command line argument

This is the command I'm running

```
!python "/content/drive/My Drive/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py" --model_dir="/content/drive/My Drive/Tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8" --pipeline_config_path="/content/drive/My Drive/Tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/pipeline.config"
```

There doesn't seem to be any mistake in it.

This is the stack trace

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 110, in main
    record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 630, in train_loop
    manager.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_management.py", line 819, in save
    self._record_state()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_management.py", line 728, in _record_state
    save_relative_paths=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_management.py", line 248, in update_checkpoint_state_internal
    text_format.MessageToString(ckpt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 570, in atomic_write_string_to_file
    rename(temp_pathname, filename, overwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 529, in rename
    rename_v2(oldname, newname, overwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 546, in rename_v2
    compat.as_bytes(src), compat.as_bytes(dst), overwrite)
```

Error message:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: /content/drive/My Drive/Tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint.tmp91048f3bf67645619be6603094546de1; Is a directory
```

The error is raised from `_pywrap_file_io.RenameFile()`, where `_pywrap_file_io` is imported from `tensorflow.python`. I tried to look into the source code to find the problem, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Could the problem have arraised because I'm running this on **colab** ?

Tensorflow version: 2.3
Python version: 3.6

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Try to change your _model_dir_ to one different from the loaded one and make sure the new one is empty.

Comment: Yeah, that should work. The problem was the program was trying to create a file with the name "checkpoint" but there was a folder with the same name in the downloaded model. I'm my case I changed the folder name to "checkpoint0" and it worked fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You should answer your question and mark it as resolved then if some people have the same issue!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that the program was trying to create a file with the name "checkpoint" but there was a folder with the same name in the downloaded model.
There are two ways to overcome this issue,

1. Create a new folder and set its path as the argument for *--model_dir*
2. Check if there is a folder named '*checkpoint*', if there is, then change the folder name. In my case, I changed it to '*checkpoint0*'.

Comment: You might also have to change the value of fine_tune_checkpoint in pipeline.config